# Creating a Corresponding Array to a char Array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

If

```
char [] a = {'x','y','x'};
```

I need an

```
int [] b={5,3,5};
```

It is clear that 'x' correspond to 5 and 'y' corresponds to 3.

I tried to get  this way through JAVA code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    char [] a= {'x','y','x'};
    int[] b ={};

    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    if( a[i]=='x'){
        b[i]=3;
    } else {
        b[i]=5;
    }

    System.out.println(b[i]);
    }

    }}
```

but failed. I need help.

Comment: How did you fail? Why does your solution not work as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the `b` array like:

```
int[] b = new int[a.length];
```

And also, since you want `x` to correspond to `5`, you have to do:

```
if(a[i] == 'x') {
    b[i] = 5;
} else {
    b[i] = 3;
}
```

Comment: I have seen your detailed solution on the above link. I think it is very valuable for newbies like me.

Comment: @user3660819 Don't hesitate to use this website to share sample with your futures questions :).

Comment: Yes, I will never hesitate.